# flask dynamic form creation from dict data

Tags: python, flask

I got a python dict like this-

```
{'_ip address_': {'os_version': 'cisco', 'hostname': '_Device name_'}, 
'_ip address_': {'os_version': 'cisco', 'hostname': '_Device name_'},
'_ip address_': {'os_version': None, 'hostname': '_Device name_'}, 
'_ip address_': {'os_version': 'cisco', 'hostname': '_Device name_'}, 
'_ip address_': {'os_version': 'cisco', 'hostname': '_Device name_'},
'_ip address_': {'os_version': 'brocade', 'hostname': '_Device name_'}, 
'_ip address_': {'os_version': 'huawei', 'hostname': '_Device name_'},
```

i want to create a page that creates forms based on device type and create a command field. it creates a page like this-

---

### Device list:cisco

multiple *device names*

### Command input

TextAreaField >for command input

---

### Device list:brocade

multiple_device names_

### Command input

TextAreaField >for command input

---

but when i fill the form and submit its only getting data from the first textarea. how do i get all data from all text area back to my python program.

initial function to create the form-
        return render_template('code_inject.html', form=form, model_list = l1, 
        ipdict= ipdict_final)

to get form data in another function-

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
    command = request.form.get('content')
    form_id = request.form.get('form_id')
```

---

my code is like this-

```
<table class="table-bordered" border="2"  width="1%">
<tbody>
                <form action = "http://10.226.110.9:8080/codeinjectexe"  
                       method = "post" runat="server" 
                    enctype="multipart/form-data" >


                    {% for model in model_list %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value={{model}}> 
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{form.title.label}} {{model}}</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>{% for key , value in ipdict.items() %}
                            {% if value["os_version"] == model %}
                                <td><h5>{{value["hostname"]}}
                            {% endif %}
                         </td>
                         {% endfor %}

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>{{form.content.label}}</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>{{form.content}}</td>
                    </tr>

                    </form>

                {% endfor %}
                {{ form.submit (class="btn btn-danger btn-block") }}

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

i am new to flask.
thanks in advance.

Comment: did you pass your dict to the html template?

Comment: first: your `dict` definition is broken, there should be a closing bracket, second: there are duplicate keys which in the end will be replaced by one of them

Comment: thanks for your comments. i am able to get the display. but not able to get the input value back from all text fields. updated the issue